# Delete field in doc using spring esTemplate

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

I'm trying to use ElasticsearchTemplate to update my es data,code is as follows:

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
            updateRequest.index(RiskViewDevStatistics.ESIndex);
            updateRequest.type(RiskViewDevStatistics.ESType);
            try {
                updateRequest.doc(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
                        .field("owner", ownerId)
                        .endObject());
                UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId("docId")
                        .withClass(RiskViewDevStatistics.class).withUpdateRequest(updateRequest).build();
                esTemplate.update(updateQuery);
```

The code is similar to :

```
update owner from xx where id = xx
```

When the argument ownerId I passed in is null,data in es is :

```
"hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "st-riskview",
                "_type": "riskviewdevstatistics",
                "_id": "AW47Wy7cEY_O-MqaGSGL",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "owner": null  // null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

My question is : 
**How to delete this field instead of setting it to null ?**

Attention:I don't want to replace total doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
POST st-riskview/riskviewdevstatistics/AW47Wy7cEY_O-MqaGSGL/_update
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.remove('owner')"
}
```

Spring - not tested

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(RiskViewDevStatistics.ESIndex,RiskViewDevStatistics.ESType,"docid");
Map<String, Object> parameters = singletonMap("field", "owner");
Script inline = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source.remove(params.field)",parameters);  
updateRequest.script(inline);
```

[Updates with a script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-update.html)

Comment: it goes error:`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [painless]`.Does this have anything to do with my es version,which is 2.4

Comment: It  works after i add `script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on` to my elasticsearch.yml